# How can I extend bathroom fixture supply pipes for sink and hand-held bidet for suspended toilet WC?

Tags: toilet, pipe, sink

How can I extend the water pipeline for the sink, hand bidet and attach the evacuation pipe attached to the toilet and also to the sink?

We plan to install a wall-hung/suspended toilet and will use Geberit Duofix - Frame for the wall-hung WC. I have also attached the image of the design that we want to follow. I would like to add a bidet just like the image but I am wondering how one can do so with a wall-hung toilet.

I would love some advice from people who have done so. It's an apartment we own in France.

[image: my poor attempt of drawing the toilet's blueprint]

[image]

[image: The toilet design we plan to follow]

Comment: Please do not ask the same question again.  Instead edit the previous one to provide more information.